# Re-direct a file save operation to a stream or memory buffer in C#

Tags: c#, file, redirect, buffer

A third party library I'm working with has both Save and Load functions which are passed a string parameter which is a filename. Instead of saving and loading files on disk, I want to use memory buffers.

Without changing the library, is there a way to redirect the file to a memory buffer from entirely within my application?

(Outside the application I could use a RAM disk or something, but I'm looking for a solution which is entirely self-contained)

Comment: Can you ask the library creator to provide overloads of these functions with a Stream parameter?

Comment: If we can simply ask them then this question probably wouldn't exist.